# Adding buttons on top of activity

Tags: android, android-layout, button

I want to add some buttons on top of the activity layout (marked it in the picture) but could not find how to do this. What phrases should i search for?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ben P said, thats called Menu.

You need to create an XML with the options, and in the activity render the XML.

Example, lets call this menu_test.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_download"
       android:title="@string/download_information"
       android:orderInCategory="100"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_file_download_white_24dp"
       app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

As you can see on the guide, showAsAction will display the icon if have one, or the title if it hasnt. If you remove that line, its added to the three points button.

Now in the activity

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_test, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_download) {
        //YOUR METHOD HERE
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

The buttons that appear there (both text and icons) are items in what's called the *Options Menu*. Developer guides for creating options menus are here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not what i was talking about. I would like to create for ex. one button, and onclick it would call some method.

Comment: Create a menu with one item. Use the attribute `app:showAsAction="ifRoom"` and provide an icon. Implement `onCreateOptionsMenu` to display this menu and `onOptionsItemSelected` to handle the user clicking it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove actionbar from activity. You can set NoActionBar theme for the activity. And in your layout xml, you can add toolbar which includes buttons like following code.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#131313"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00aaaaaa"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:text="Delete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="#000"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And in onCreate() function, you can add following code:

```
Toolbar topToolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(topToolBar);
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();;
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```